# Issue with if /elseif /else

Tags: php, function, methods, control-structure

I am creating a whitelist if you will for a user to input data. I am getting stuck on the elseif statements.

This is my code :

```
public function is_valid_data($data)
   {

     if(strlen($data > 9))
     {
       $this -> set_message('is_valid_data', 'Field needs to be less than 9 characters');
       return FALSE;
     }
     elseif(strlen($data < 9))
     {
       $this -> set_message('is_valid_data', 'Field can not be under 9 characters');
       return FALSE;
     }
     elseif((substr($str, 0, 1) !== 'testing') || (substr($str, 0, 1) !== 'test'))
     {
       $this -> set_message('is_valid_data', 'Please re-submit data!');
       return FALSE;
     }
     elseif(!preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $str))
     {
       $this -> set_message('is_valid_data', 'Please dont forget about the numbers!');
       return FALSE;
     }
     else
     {
       return TRUE;
     }

   }
```

For some reason even if $data is 9 characters the first if statements goes through, then the second one fails and I keep getting 'Field can not be under 9 characters' even though the $data is exactly 9 characters. I am returning false because in another script I have the function call is_valid_data($data) and if this function returns a false then it will return the error to the user. If it returns true then the data is valid and we can continue

I can't seem to shake this issue.

Comment: You want to compare the result of `strlen($data)` to 9, you have the comparison inside the function call right now: `strlen($data) > 9` is not the same as `strlen($data < 9)` - see the difference?

Comment: Yea... I'm a noob I didn't even notice the issue :( Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(strlen($data) > 9)
```

instead of

```
if(strlen($data > 9))
```

Comment: I would accept this answer but I can't. That is such a dumb mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And I can't vote you up either. But this did work

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `$data < 9` it means it should be smaller then 9, if you want it to allow 9 as well then you'll need `<=` smaller than or equal to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking the conditions wrong.  What you need is 
replace the

```
if(strlen($data > 9))
```

with

```
if(strlen($data) > 9)
```

The same syntctical problem is also present in the second `if` statement. What you might want is to replace

```
elseif(strlen($data < 9))
```

by

```
elseif(strlen($data) < 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with that code what is $str is this a member of Class is it a global i need to know these things in order to help. Thanks

Comment: or the reply below :) or my example with the below fixes http://pastebin.com/zJbQGzUP